# Connect Linode servers to a disk on another server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, linode

I have three servers with Linode: A DB server and two web servers running Wordpress. The DB server also has a disk image called 'Shared Media', which I'd like to be accessible from the web servers (they're in the same data center).

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NFS via the private linode network. Simple, easy to set up, no fuss.